# How can I use pagination when I am using a form to input a date and submitting that form sends a post request and pagination accepts get request?

Tags: html, django, pagination, django-views

I am using django to display a webpage. I want to display details of files from database. These files can be of any number. I am using a form to input a date from HTML file which is accepted by a django view function. This function checks if the request is of type POST and returns the data between the mentioned date. Now when I use pagination to display these pages, pressing the next doesn't show anything as this time the request gets changed to GET. In my django view function, data is fetched in a list. Every file's data is in a list. So, all the data consists lists of lists. How will I be able to display these lists using pagination without sending the requests again. Is it possible to do so?

My data is stored in a database according to dates. I am fetching the data in a given range. This range comes from html page. Here is how I am trying to fetch the details:

```
<div class="container">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="date" name="start_date">
    <input type="date" name="end_date">
    <button type="Submit">Get Details</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is the code that I use at the backend to serve the webpage.

```
def data_range(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form(request.POST)
        try:
            if form.is_valid():
                start_date = form.data.get('start_date')
                end_date = form.data.get('end_date')
                page_data = get_page_details(start_date, end_date)

            else:

                current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
                start_date = end_date = current_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                page_data = get_page_details(start_date, end_date)

        except Exception:
            return render(request, 'UserInterface/no_data_fort.html', {'list_item_count': 0})
    else:
        return render(request, 'UserInterface/no_data_fort.html', {'list_item_count': 0})

    if page_data:
        # Calculating total files in fortnightly data
        list_item_count = len(page_data)

        # Adding Paginator or pagination
        paginator = Paginator(page_data, 1)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        data = paginator.get_page(page)

        return render(request, 'UserInterface/fortnightly_range.html', {'page_data_list': data, 'list_item_count': list_item_count})
    else:
        return render(request, 'UserInterface/no_data_fort.html', {'list_item_count': 0})
```

`page_data` that I fetch is a list of lists.

Comment: Show us the code of what you're doing. But as a first quick comment: Why use POST to submit a filter that just queries data? If the submission doesn't save anything to your db, it should be a GET (that way you can add the initial filter params in the url for your next button)

Comment: I have edited the question with the code details. @dirkgroten

Comment: As I said, it would be easier if your use GET for your form instead of POST. Then in your "next page" button url, you can include the parameters for the start date and end date as regular url parameters.